# Smoothing page views over time to find truthfully most popular overall

Tags: sql, database, statistics

I have a year's worth of page views for articles, each with a published-at timestamp and page view total. Being that all the stories from the beginning of the year have accumulated the highest totals, I'd like to smooth things out a little bit and find the overall most popular articles, taking into account that some have that have been very popular have not had nearly as much time as others.

Should I be focusing on the relationship between page views and time since publication? How best can I smooth these articles?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, the relationship between `page views` and `time since publication` is important.

Perhaps this is too obvious but you could compare views-per-day averages instead of total views.  `views_per_day = views / days_since_publication`  Of course, you would only do this calculation for pages 1 day old or older.  Pages in their first day: `views_per_day = views`

Comment: i've found that doing this prioritizes the most recent content over the oldest.

Comment: Try 'weighting' the view averages by squaring the number of views before dividing by the document age.  This way, a document that was viewed 100 times over 100 days will have a view index of 100, while a document that was viewed 1 time in 1 day will only have a view index of 1, and a document that was viewed 10 times in 1 day will have a view index of 100.  Sorta levels the playing field a little better.  You might find some actual statistics could help you here, though I can't think of anything atm.

Comment: view_index = views * views / days_since_publication